# Export multiple wrapper functions in Javascript ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, ecmascript-6

I'm using react-komposer to wrap React components with a data fetching wrapper.

It is very basic and I'd want to wrap multiple components in Meteor. But I can't figure out what the export pattern is?

Here is what I have (and gives me an "Unexpected Token" error - probably obvious if you understand this well!):

```
// myContainer.jsx
import Component1 from './Component1.jsx';
import Component2 from './Component2.jsx';

function composer(props, onData) {
  if (Meteor.subscribe('SingleTodoLists').ready()) {
    const todoList = todoLists.find({}).fetch();
    onData(null, { todoList });
  }
}

export composeWithTracker(composer, Loading)(Component1);
export composeWithTracker(composer, Loading)(Component2);
```

And I'd like to import them like this:

```
import { Component1, Component2 } from './myContainer.jsx';
```

This wrapper syntax is not really clear for me, so I'm unsure about what to try. Playing with export default and other variations yielded no result so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use default exports, you need to name the things you export:

```
export const TrackedComponent1 = composeWithTracker(composer, Loading)(Component1);
export const TrackedComponent2 = composeWithTracker(composer, Loading)(Component2);
```

If you use default export instead you can omit the name, e.g.

```
export default composeWithTracker(composer, Loading)(Component1);
```

But you can only define one default export per module

See the documentation for the ES6 export syntax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

**Update:**

If you want to keep the original export names:

```
import _Component1 from './Component1.jsx';
import _Component2 from './Component2.jsx';

//... you code here

export composeWithTracker(composer, Loading)(_Component1);
export composeWithTracker(composer, Loading)(_Component2);
```

Because Component1.jsx uses a default exports, when you import it you can rename it as you want (e.g. _Component1, UntrackedComponent1, ...). Without a default export, you could have used `import { Component1 } as _Component1` instead.

Comment: Great! It is not really necessary, but is there really no way to use the original names `Component1` and `Component2`? I could use a temporary variable and then reassign Component1 and 2 in the export, but that isn't really clean.

Comment: At your update the line `export composeWithTracker(composer, Loading)(_Component1);` shouldn't be `export const Component = composeWithTracker(composer, Loading)(_Component1);`?